# How to get a user's details using mysql by calling soap webservices?

Tags: android, mysql, ksoap2

I am developing an Android project for MySQL database connection using SOAP WebServices.

In my database I have 3 fields (username, password, email).

Here I insert the values for 3 users. I created a webservice code for a login form.

The login form code is:

```
package com.userlogin.ws;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Login {
    public String authentication(String userName, String password) {

        String retrievedUserName = "";
        String retrievedPassword = "";
        String status = "";
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androidlogin", "root", "");
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" + userName + "'");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                retrievedUserName = result.getString("username");
                retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
            }

            if (retrievedUserName.equals(userName) && retrievedPassword.equals(password)) {
                status = "Success!";

            } else {
                status = "Login fail!!!";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;

    }

}
```

The forgetpassword. webservice code is:

```
package com.userlogin.ws;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class ForgetPassword {
    public String customerData(){
        String customerInfo = "";
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androidlogin","root","");
            //Find customer information where the customer ID is maximum
            PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = (SELECT username FROM user)");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            while(result.next()){
                customerInfo = customerInfo + result.getString("username") + "&" + result.getString("password") + "&"+result.getString("email");
                //Here "&"s are added to the return string. This is help to split the string in Android application
            }
        }

        catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }

        return customerInfo;
    }

}
```

If I clicked *forgetpassword* the application should start the  next `Activity`.

The next `Activity` should ask for email, id..

After entering the mail id, it should proceed to yet another `Activity` and to display that particular person password only.

Which query should I use?

Comment: the above code is successfully when only 1 user details there in my mysql database.it is not successfully for more number of user.so please help me

Answer (score 0):

To get Particular user details,

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 'XXX(Enter the name of the user)'
```

To get any one user details

```
SELECT * FROM user limit 1
```

To get password for particular user using email

```
SELECT password FROM user where email = "XXX(Enter the email of the user)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user with the maximum id:

```
SELECT max(id) as Max, id FROM user having id = Max
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**Edit:**

If I understand the edited question *what I'm not sure I am), your problem is here:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = (SELECT username FROM user)"
```

this code select all users in the db, that's why the code works for you for only one user.

in your forget password you want to change the user's password with the given email, so it's suppose to be like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=" + usersemail
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't quite tell what exactly you meant based on the question, but based on the commenting you had in the code stating

> ## Find customer information WHERE the customer ID IS maximum

Then you are looking for the user information of the most recent user (assuming you have an auto incrementing user id and could use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u1, (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM user) AS m1 WHERE u1.id=m1.maxid;
```

or you could do it without a subselect

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Cheers